# SQL select and case combined

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with a select statement and not sure what I am doing wrong.  This is the structure of the source table:

> Source Schema DATA1
>
> Source Table FOLDERS
>
> Source Columns  FOLDERID, USERID
>
> Destination Schema DATA1
>
> Destination Table FOLDER_USER
>
> Destination Columns  FOLDER_ID, USER_ID

And here is the query ( I need to change the folder ID as it is being pulled out of the first query hence the case):

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
   FOR FOLDER_ROW IN (SELECT FOLDERID = CASE 
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '10' THEN '1'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '565' THEN '2'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '11' THEN '3'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '81' THEN '4'
                                ELSE '0'
                            END, USERID FROM DATA1.FOLDERS WHERE UPPER(OWNER) = 'ADMIN')
      LOOP                       
          INSERT INTO DATA1.FOLDER_USER (FOLDER_ID, CORP_ID) VALUES (FOLDER_ROW.FOLDERID, FOLDER_ROW.CORPID);
     END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I get the following error when I execute and I'm stuck as to why I am getting it.  I know it has something to do with the case inside the select:

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 39:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06550: line 3, column 22:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: Why so complicated? This can be done without the loop by using INSERT ... SELECT directly. That will be a **lot** faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT FOLDERID = CASE is wrong.  It should be SELECT CASE ..... END As FOLDERID

Comment: Thanks, so simple yet its been driving me nuts for so long.  I think I tried every other combination of select case other than this!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want

```
BEGIN
   FOR FOLDER_ROW IN (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '10' THEN '1'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '565' THEN '2'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '11' THEN '3'
                                WHEN FOLDERID = '81' THEN '4'
                                ELSE '0'
                            END folder_id, 
                            USERID 
                       FROM DATA1.FOLDERS 
                     WHERE UPPER(OWNER) = 'ADMIN')
      LOOP                       
          INSERT INTO DATA1.FOLDER_USER (FOLDER_ID, CORP_ID) VALUES (FOLDER_ROW.FOLDER_ID, FOLDER_ROW.CORPID);
     END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I added an alias of `FOLDER_ID` to the `CASE` statement and eliminated the `FOLDERID =` bit from the `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

You could also rewrite it as a `decode`
(it is less portable and harder to read though)

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN    
    FOR folder_row IN (SELECT DECODE(folderid,'10', '1','565','2','11', '3','81', '4','0') AS folderid , 
                              userid 
                       FROM data1.folders 
                       WHERE UPPER(owner) = 'ADMIN')       
    LOOP                                  
        INSERT INTO data1.folder_user (folder_id, corp_id) VALUES (folder_row.folderid, folder_row.corpid);      
    END LOOP;     
    COMMIT; 
END;
```

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions042.htm

Comment: If the OP is using Oracle 8i or above it's probably better to use the ANSI compatible CASE over DECODE as it has several advantages(http://oracledoug.com/decode.html)

Comment: I would guess that's why I wrote 'less portable and harder to read' !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have simplified your code or not before posting the question, but I would look at getting rid of the CURSOR FOR loop completely and just using and INSERT statement with a sub-query.

I think CURSOR FOR loops are pretty well optimized by Oracle so it may not run any faster but might be easier to understand.

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DATA1.FOLDER_USER (FOLDER_ID, CORP_ID) 
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN FOLDERID = '10' THEN '1'
      WHEN FOLDERID = '565' THEN '2'
      WHEN FOLDERID = '11' THEN '3'
      WHEN FOLDERID = '81' THEN '4'
      ELSE '0'
    END folder_id, 
    USERID 
  FROM DATA1.FOLDERS 
  WHERE UPPER(OWNER) = 'ADMIN';

  COMMIT;
END;
```